# Find every $z$s that fit $\cos(z) = -2$

Tags: complex-numbers

I couldn't find any, I tried to write $\cos(z)$ as $\cos(x)\cos(iy)-\sin(x)\sin(iy)$ which then gave me

$\cos(x)\cosh(y) - i\sin(x)\sinh(y) = -2$

$\sin(x)=0$ so that imaginary part become $0$

now we have to find $\cosh(y) = -2$ which is not true for no $y$.

is it right or i made a mistake in my substitutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: start with
$$
\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}
$$
and obtain a quadratic equation for $e^{iz}$.

Comment: i got $\exp(iz) = -2+\sqrt(3)$ and $\exp(iz) = -2-\sqrt(3)$ which gets me that $e^x = -2+\sqrt(3)$ which is negative on the right side and impossible :-?

Comment: If $e^{iz}=-2\pm\sqrt{3}$ then $$e^{iz+i\pi}=e^{i\pi}(-2\pm\sqrt{3})=(-1)(-2\pm\sqrt{3})=2\pm\sqrt{3}$$ whith positive RHS.

Comment: What should $z$ be btw?

Comment: @no0ob Do you follow the argumentation? If $$e^{i(z+\pi)}=2\pm\sqrt{3}$$ then how to find $i(z+\pi)$?

Comment: Ok i think i had a mistake i just assumed $x = 0$ in my original post, i could use $x=\pi$ too

Comment: Cause with your path i just have to solve the thing again but this time with a new $x$ like $x' = x+\pi$ so if $x=0$ then $ x'=\pi$

Comment: @no0ob You could use $x=\pi k$ for any integer $k$ (all solutions to $\sin x=0$).

Comment: as you see i couldn't done that with $0$ cause it made $cos(x)ch(y) = 1*ch(y) = -2$ which is negative RHS

Comment: @no0ob Right, sorry, it should be every second zero of $\sin x=0$ to make $\cos x=-1$, i.e. $x=\pi+2\pi k$.

Answer (score 2):

I should have used $x=(2k+1)\pi$ for the $x$ and then had the

$\cos( (2k+1)\pi ) \cosh(y) = -2$

which made it $\cosh(y) = 2$

Comment: Right, and here you get two solutions for $y$ with $\pm$ (recall $2\pm\sqrt{3}$ in another approach).

Comment: Yes; since $\cos x\cosh y<0$, you need to have $\cos x<0$ and therefore $x=\pi+2k\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Be:
$$
\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=-2
$$
Then:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} &=& -2 \\
e^{iz}+e^{-iz} &=& -4  \\
e^{2iz} + 1 &=& -4e^{iz}  \\
\left(e^{iz}\right)^2 + 4\left(e^{iz}\right) + 1 &=& 0  \\
e^{iz} &=& \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{16-4}}{2}     \\
e^{iz} &=& -2 \pm \sqrt{3}     \\
\end{eqnarray}
Then since $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$, $e^{iz}=e^{i(z+2k\pi)}$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$: 
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{i(z+2k_1\pi)} &=& -2 \pm \sqrt{3}     \\
i(z +2k_1\pi) &=& \ln\left(-2 \pm \sqrt{3}\right) \\
z &=& 2k_1\pi - i\ln\left(-2 \pm \sqrt{3}\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}
There are two set solution to differents solutions:
\begin{eqnarray}
z_{+} &=& 2k_1\pi - i\ln\left(-2 + \sqrt{3}\right) \\
z_{-} &=& 2k_1\pi - i\ln\left(-2 - \sqrt{3}\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}
For $z_{-}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
z_{-} &=& 2k_1\pi - i\ln\left(\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)e^{-i(1+2k_2)\pi}\right) \\
z_{-} &=& 2k_1\pi - i\left[\ln\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)-i(1+2k_2)\pi\right] \\
z_{-} &=& 2k_1\pi - (1+2k_2)\pi - i\ln\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right) \\
z_{-} &=& (1+2k)\pi - i\ln\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}
Then, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ the solutions are:
\begin{eqnarray}
z_{+} &=& 2k\pi - i\ln\left(-2 + \sqrt{3}\right) \\
z_{-} &=& (1+2k)\pi - i\ln\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: you mean $2k\pi + 1$

Comment: Why $2k\pi +1$?

Comment: Cause i had answered my approach using $(2k+1)\pi$ there should be one solution i believe :-?

Comment: oh, okey, I'm going to fix it

Comment: Now it is correct i believe

Comment: @ElPasta Still you haven't fixed $2k\pi$ to $(2k+1)\pi$

Comment: But I don't believe that is incorrect

Comment: The only annoyance is that $\ln(-2\pm\sqrt{3})$ is *complex* logarithm. Would be better to change the sign first by $e^{i\pi}$ then use the real logarithm instead.

Comment: This is at least misleading. The number $-2-\sqrt{3}$ is, in trigonometric form, $(2+\sqrt{3})e^{i\pi}$, so its logarithms are $\ln(2+\sqrt{3})+i(\pi+2n\pi)$.

Comment: $|-2\pm\sqrt{3}|=\sqrt{7}$ is nonsense. Are you thinking of $-2\pm\color{red}{i}\sqrt{3}$ here?

Comment: I think that I fixed it