# If $z=x+iy$ is the answer of the equation $\cos(z)=-3$ What is the value of $x$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> If $z=x+iy$ is the answer of the equation $\cos(z)=-3$. What is the value
> of $x$?
>
> $1)x=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}2 , k\in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> $2)x=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2 , k\in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> $3)x=k\pi+\frac{\pi}2 , k\in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> $4)x=k\pi-\frac{\pi}2 , k\in \mathbb{Z}$

I saw a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059995/find-every-zs-that-fit-cosz-2?noredirect=1&lq=1), and I tried to solve it but I got stock at a point. Here is my try:

$$\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=-3\Rightarrow e^{iz}+e^{-iz}+6=0$$
After using the substitution $e^{iz}=t$  we get $t^2+6t+1=0$. Hence $e^{i(z+2k\pi)}= -3\pm\sqrt8$ and

$$i(z+2k\pi)=\ln(-3\pm2\sqrt2)$$
From here I don't know how to continue.

Comment: We are all agreed that the correct answer is None of the Above (specifically, $2k\pi+\pi$). Are you sure you copied the question correctly?

Comment: @TonyK Yes I just double checked it and I copied correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{iz} = e^{i(x+iy)}= -3\pm\sqrt8 \implies \underbrace{e^{-y}}_{>0}\ e^{ix}= -3\pm\sqrt8<0$$

$$ \implies e^{ix}\in \mathbb{R}_{<0} \implies x=(2k+1)\pi,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
z &= 2\pi k \pm \cos^{-1}(-3), \; k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
&= 2\pi k \pm \frac{\pi}{2} \pm \sin^{-1}(3)\\
& = 2\pi k \pm \frac{\pi}{2} \pm i\ln\left(\sqrt{1 - 3^2} - 3i\right)\\
& = 2\pi k \pm \frac{\pi}{2} \pm i\ln\left(i\left(2\sqrt{2} - 3\right)\right)\\
& = 2\pi k \pm \frac{\pi}{2} \pm i\ln(i) \pm i\ln\left(2\sqrt{2} - 3\right)\\
& = 2\pi k \pm \frac{\pi}{2} \mp \frac{\pi}{2} \pm i\ln\left(2\sqrt{2} - 3\right)\\
& = 2\pi k \pm i\ln\left(2\sqrt{2} - 3\right)\\
& = 2\pi k \mp \pi  \pm i\ln\left(3 - 2\sqrt{2}\right)
\end{align}

$$\therefore \boxed{\Re(z) = (2n + 1)\pi, \; n \in \mathbb{Z}}$$

**Reference:** [Inverse trigonometric functions: Logarithmic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I hadn't vote any answer yet. I don't know who downvoted.

Comment: I guess 1. Too much equations, most students are not comfortable with a lot of math equations being thrown at them. Looks good to me though